# Getting Request from FritzBox TR-064 API fails

Tags: api, soap, fritzbox

I'm trying since days to get the info of via Wifi connected hosts from my FritzRepeater which is offering an SOAP API for that. I'm using curl... everything is working fine until I have to use arguments/parameters. It seems like I'm missing something about the correct body format.

```
For example - working request NOT using arguments:
location="/upnp/control/deviceinfo"
uri="urn:dslforum-org:service:DeviceInfo:1"
action="GetInfo"
par=""
param=""

curl -k -m 5 --anyauth -u "$FRITZUSER:$FRITZPW" http://$IP:49000$location \
        -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"' \
        -H "SoapAction:$uri#$action" \
        -d "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                        <s:Envelope s:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
                                <s:Body>
                                        <u:$action xmlns:u='$uri'>
                                                $param
                                        </u:$action>
                                </s:Body>
                        </s:Envelope>"
```

RESPONSE:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body>
<u:GetInfoResponse xmlns:u="urn:dslforum-org:service:DeviceInfo:1">
<NewManufacturerName>AVM</NewManufacturerName>
<NewManufacturerOUI>00040E</NewManufacturerOUI>
<NewModelName>FRITZ!WLAN Repeater 310</NewModelName>
<NewDescription>FRITZ!WLAN Repeater 310 122.06.92</NewDescription>
<NewProductClass>FRITZ!WLAN Repeater</NewProductClass>
<NewSerialNumber>9CC7A6D3BE8F</NewSerialNumber>
<NewSoftwareVersion>122.06.92</NewSoftwareVersion>
<NewHardwareVersion>FRITZ!WLAN Repeater 310</NewHardwareVersion>
<NewSpecVersion>1.0</NewSpecVersion>
<NewProvisioningCode></NewProvisioningCode>
<NewUpTime>296364</NewUpTime>
<NewDeviceLog></NewDeviceLog>
</u:GetInfoResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And the same with parameters/args:

```
location="/upnp/control/wlanconfig1"
uri="urn:dslforum-org:service:WLANConfiguration:1"
action="GetGenericAssociatedDeviceInfo"
par="NewAssociatedDeviceIPAddress"
param="<s:$par></s:$par>"

curl -k -m 5 --anyauth -u "$FRITZUSER:$FRITZPW" http://$IP:49000$location \
        -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"' \
        -H "SoapAction:$uri#$action" \
        -d "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                        <s:Envelope s:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
                                <s:Body>
                                        <u:$action xmlns:u='$uri'>
                                                $param
                                        </u:$action>
                                </s:Body>
                        </s:Envelope>"
```

RESPONSE:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>UPnPError</faultstring>
<detail>
<UPnPError xmlns="urn:dslforum-org:control-1-0">
<errorCode>402</errorCode>
<errorDescription>Invalid Args</errorDescription>
</UPnPError>
</detail>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
```

Anybody have an idea of what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The manual [`wlanconfigSCPD.pdf`](https://avm.de/service/schnittstellen/)
lists the input parameter `NewAssociatedDeviceIndex` instead of `NewAssociatedDeviceIPAddress`.
The parameter `NewAssociatedDeviceIndex` requires a numeric value from `0` to result of `GetTotalAssociations()` minus `1`.

Comment: The parameter **NewAssociatedDeviceIPAddress** does exist as well, but it requires the IP address as input (e.g., **param="<s:$par>192.168.178.92</s:$par>"**) and the action **X_AVM-DE_GetSpecificAssociatedDeviceInfoByIp** instead of **GetGenericAssociatedDeviceInfo**, which could be called after the latter with the delivered IP-address.